# pageBlockTable onRowClick cant see var

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a `pageBlockTable` that loops through a list of objects. 
I'm trying add an `onRowClick` event so I can use the clicked row as data for a javascript function.
However when saving in the developer console, I'm getting the error :-

> (Unknown property 'ContactStandardController.c')

What am I doing wrong, why is it looking at the controller and not the `pageBlockTable` var?

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contact}" var="c" onRowClick="alert('{!c.Name}');">
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Here the approach is wrong. `{!Contact}` is a single instance. It should not be used with `<dataTable/>`. It will result nothing. It should be a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a limitation of how the system works; you can't reference the variable until you're already inside the table. If you want to get the information about the row, you can do so through `event.target`. Here's a little demo I wrote up that alerts a contact's Id when you click anywhere on the row:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <script>
    function handle(event) {
        alert(event.target.querySelector('.rowId').dataset.rowId);
    }
    </script>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="c" onRowClick="handle(event)">
            <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
                <span class="rowId" data-row-id="{!c.Id}" />
                {!c.Name}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!c.Email}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

To demo this in your org, remember to add `?id=<some-account-id>` to the URL to view this in action. `event.target` is the row that was clicked.

Comment: All other examples if using onRowClick i could find seem to do exactly what I'm trying for i.e.
[link]http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134366/onrowclick-in-pageblocktable-tag-not-working
[link]https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094aFIAQ

Comment: @CliffB In both those answers, they eventually just attached an onclick handler to each cell in the table; that's not the same as having the merge fields in the onRowClick handler. For what it's worth, I did attempt a version of your own code in my developer org before generating my answer, which I often do just to confirm/reproduce the problem, before independently coming up with the solution I presented. If there were a way to do it, I'm sure that between Adrian, myself, and Ashwani, we would have (probably) found a fix if one were to be had.

Comment: @CliffB On the other hand, you *could* use an `apex:repeat` element, and render your own `tr` elements with an onclick handler, which would be functionally the same, but it would not be an `apex:pageBlockTable`; you'd have to do all the styling yourself.

Comment: Fair enough, this will do what i need. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `c` variable is only in scope *between* your opening and closing `<apex:pageBlockTable>` tags. In this case, you should just use `alert('{!Contact.Name}')`.

Comment: This would reference the table not the row I'm clicking

Comment: There can only be one row...

Answer (score 0):

Here the approach is wrong. `{!Contact}` is a single instance. It should not be used with `<PageBlockTable/>`. It will result nothing. Also, `var` scope is in only inside the tag not with the tag itself.

Anyways, here is the way to access the column if `Contact` is a list:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contact}" var="c" onRowClick="alert(this.firstChild.innerHTML);">
            <apex:column >{!c.Name}</apex:column>
            <apex:column >{!c.Id}</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```